# Management studio bug

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

This is on SQL 2008 R2 x64

I have installed management studio on all the computers at work, but for no apparent reason my management studio does not work on one of them. I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it twice now.

Symptoms: Management studio start but freezes, there is no connection screen that appears but when I try to stop the process it says that there is a connection prompt screen open (but really there is not).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the machine ever set up for multiple monitors? If so, it's possible the connection prompt is being displayed on the other one; try disabling the second monitor, or using Alt-Space M, then use the arrow keys to try to move the prompt to a visible location.